# Using AFNetworking 1.0 disabling ARC for specific files

Tags: ios, json, xcode, parsing

I'm using AFNetworking 1.0 in my app. I've tried the example NetworkingIsFun, and that's exactly what I need in my app. I've imported the AFNetworking files to my project and disabled ARC mode by typing **-fno-objc-arc** for all of the .m-files in **Compile Sources**.

In the example, I can successfully parse my JSON file to the Table View, but in my app nothing happens. Has this something to do with the disabled ARC mode files?

This is the code I'm using:

```
#import "Pictures.h"
#import "DEMONavigationController.h"
#import "PicturesObject.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

@interface Pictures ()

@end

@implementation Pictures

@synthesize tableView = _tableView, activityIndicatorView = _activityIndicatorView, movies = _movies;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Pictures";
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu"
                                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                            target:(DEMONavigationController *)self.navigationController
                                                                            action:@selector(showMenu)];

    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Setting Up Activity Indicator View
    self.activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    self.activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicatorView];
    [self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Initializing Data Source
    self.movies = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://my-json-file.com/picture.php?name=Name"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        self.movies = JSON;
        [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];

    [operation start];

}

// Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.movies && self.movies.count) {
        return self.movies.count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 321;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PicturesObject";

    PicturesObject *cell = (PicturesObject *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PicturesObject" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *movie = [self.movies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.title.text = [movie objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.published.text = [movie objectForKey:@"published"];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[movie objectForKey:@"link"]];
    [cell.pic setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Let me say this again:
This code works in the demo app. But not in my app when I have disabled ARC for all of the AFNetworking files.

Why? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is there a reason you using v1.0 and not a newer version which supports ARC?

Comment: My guess would be that he is following a tutorial that uses `v1.0`?

Comment: Well, I was trying to use v2.0, but I struggled with the code. I didn't know how to write the code above with the updated version... @RyanG

Comment: But why would this be a problem when I've disabled ARC? @RyanG

Comment: @DavidGabor I've updated your code for you, not 100% sure why it's not working properly, I'd probably need to look and test it to tell you - I have to post the code (from AFNetworking 2.0) as an answer as I can't post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // Success Code here *you maybe have to parse JSON yourself I can't remember*
        self.movies = responseObject;
        [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // Failure Code here
    }];
```

This is how you would do it in `AFNetworking 2.0`.